# Can an unknown Reform Jew be counted for a minyan?

Tags: halacha, minyan, reform-judaism, matrilineal-descent

Orthodox Judaism treats someone as a Jew if their mother is Jewish, or they underwent an Orthodox conversion. Reform Judaism will count someone as Jewish even if their only connection is through their father. Therefore, people who might consider themselves to be Reform Jews might not even be Jewish according to halacha. Of course, others will have the proper maternal connection.

With this in mind, if a Reform Jew is the tenth for a minyan, can he be counted?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4987/what-percentage-of-reform-jews-are-halachically-jewish

Comment: I would assume that we take someone's word for it if he says he is Jewish.

Comment: If there's doubt and an unknown person comes to make a minyan and it's almost zman, don't you either assume the person is Jewish or ask?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman But if you ask, he might say he's Jewish, when halachically he's not.

Comment: They also may have undergone reform conversion not recognised by orthodox

Comment: A director of a Kollel told us a story about how they often had exactly ten guys, including an old cigar-smoking guy with a big nose named Joseph. They said studied and then said Kaddish for months until one day the guy said (offhandedly) "Oh no, I'm not Jewish."  **(Collective head smack)**