# Are there any statistics for the fraction of orthodox jews rejecting their religion?

Tags: sin, orthodox, statistics

Is anyone familiar with any statistics regarding how many religious jews "go off the derech"?

To be clear, I am *not* asking about assimilation rates which are relatively easy to find. I would like to see some statistics regarding how often *orthodox* jews stop practicing Judaism.

Comment: This question is interesting, but unfortunately not on topic.  You could see the book "Off the Derech" by Faranak Margolese, though.

Comment: @yEz Would it be on topic to ask how many orthodox jews do not go off the derekh? Or is this a jews vs judaism thing? compare for instance to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4987/759 which was left open

Comment: @DoubleAA I figured it is about Jews and not Judaism. I would close the other one too, although I could hear someone argue about that one (this one seems more obvious to me).

Comment: I know someone who did their dissertation on OTD ,will try to find out

Comment: @yEz I've seen the book "Off the Derech". It gives no statistics or studies. Just surveys and interviews of people who have already left. Unfortunately, I'm finding the clause *except as related to Judaism* to be quite ambiguous. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: @Meh Sorry, I read it a long time ago.

Comment: @Meh [Here](http://www.pewforum.org/2013/10/01/jewish-denominational-switching/) is the PEW study on American Judaism denominational switching.  If you hover the cursor over "Orthodox" it shows you their survey results for percentages of denominational switches from orthodoxy.

Comment: @yEz and the other close-voters: I disagree. This is "about history or news of the Jewish people", precisely "*as related to Judaism*". It's about Jewish people's practice of Judaism. Consider this my reopen vote.

Comment: @DoubleAA please see above.

Comment: @yEz Thank you very much. Most appreciated.